# Getting remote database data into local database in android

Tags: android, sql-server

We want to get the remote database data into local database first and then we want to access the local database. Can you please suggest us how to approach for this with sample code. Our remote database is MSSQL Server.

Answer (score 2):

Have the app query the remote server, return the data from MSSQL to android code via JSON, insert into SQLite.

**Edit**: type MySQL to MSSQL

Comment: I'm just a beginner with android, I normally return data with XML, don't have much JSON experience do you have any good references? (books/links) on this topic?

Comment: is it possible from MSSQL Server?

Comment: @Madhuri yes, have a server side script query whatever data source you like.

Comment: could u please send an example?

Comment: @Madhuri no, this isn't a code writing service. I've given an outline of the solution. Implement my advice in whatever language you need.

Comment: Can u please send some tutorial links regarding JSON? I am new to JSON?

Comment: @Madhuri see my link for tdtje, or google for more. Learning to research things yourself is a worth while skill

Comment: {"menu": {
      "id": "file",
      "value": "File",
      "popup": {
        "menuitem": [
          {"value": "New", "onclick": "CreateNewDoc()"},
          {"value": "Open", "onclick": "OpenDoc()"},
          {"value": "Close", "onclick": "CloseDoc()"}
        ]
      }
    }}
After creating this file where should we store in eclipse ide? I have seen this code in http://www.androidcompetencycenter.com/2009/10/json-parsing-in-android/

Answer (score 0):

Get desired data from mysql ...in the form of xml from server. Parse that xml in android and fill desired java beans inside collection. then write state of object's in collection to sqlite dataabase.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest next time providing some code that indicates at least that you attempted to connect to your database first, and then if you run into trouble, someone here may be able to help. As opposed to just asking for sample code.

If you're talking about replication, I'm not sure this is possible from SQL Server to SQLite, otherwise, the answer to your question is simple, you would connect to your SQL Server database probably through some sort of exposed API, retrieve the data, parse it, and update your local SQLite Database accordingly.

Here's a link to a tutorial that covers connecting to local databases: [NotePad Tutorial](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/notepad/index.html)