# How to populate local sqlite database with remote MSSQL database in android

Tags: android

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Getting remote database data into local database in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6530115/getting-remote-database-data-into-local-database-in-android)

We have to copy the remote MSSQL database into local sqlite database in android. How to do that? Please suggest us a solution with sample code. Waiting for urgent reply.......