# Getting data from remote database in android

Tags: android

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Getting remote database data into local database in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6530115/getting-remote-database-data-into-local-database-in-android)

I am working on android application. I want to **access** the data from **remote** MSSQL Database and store it in local sqlite database. Can we get the data using php scripts. Please give me some idea regarding this. For this I will be thankful to you.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Create Web Service on the remote machine using PHP. Return the data to the phone formatted in XML, JSON and so on. On the phone create AsyncTask that connects to this service, downloads the data, parses it and stores it in sqlite.

Comment: Thank you. Can you please show a sample code on how to get the data from the php webservice.

Comment: There are a lot of articles here. Look for android http request, JSON or XML parse and so on. Do not forget to vote.

Comment: ok thank you..i will search for that